# Assigning role when creating new EC2 instance through AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know role can be assigned to instance from the console but I can't find anything about how to do it through AWS CLI tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--iam-instance-profile` switch. For example:

```
$ aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-11aa22bb --iam-instance-profile Name="s3access-profile" --key-name my-key-pair --security-groups my-security-group --subnet-id subnet-1a2b3c4d
```

See [Launching an Instance with an IAM Role Using the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#launch-instance-with-role-cli).